# Error while using node js sdk in hyperledger fabric?

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric

I m using node sdk for hyperledger fabric.i got the below error while using apiserver.js file in sdk. It only happens if i excute same query multiple time.

```
2019-11-22T09:02:35.721Z - warn: [Query]: evaluate: Query ID "[object Object]" of peer "peer0.org1.example.com:7051" failed: message=transaction returned with failure: TypeError: Assignment to constant variable., stack=Error: transaction returned with failure: TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.
    at self._endorserClient.processProposal (/home/cybrosys/VIRUS/ERC-20-with-Hyperledger-Fabric/fabcar/javascript/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/Peer.js:140:36)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/home/cybrosys/VIRUS/ERC-20-with-Hyperledger-Fabric/fabcar/javascript/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:1207:9)
    at InterceptingListener._callNext (/home/cybrosys/VIRUS/ERC-20-with-Hyperledger-Fabric/fabcar/javascript/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:568:42)
    at InterceptingListener.onReceiveStatus (/home/cybrosys/VIRUS/ERC-20-with-Hyperledger-Fabric/fabcar/javascript/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:618:8)
    at callback (/home/cybrosys/VIRUS/ERC-20-with-Hyperledger-Fabric/fabcar/javascript/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:845:24), status=500, , url=grpcs://localhost:7051, name=peer0.org1.example.com:7051, grpc.max_receive_message_length=-1, grpc.max_send_message_length=-1, grpc.keepalive_time_ms=120000, grpc.http2.min_time_between_pings_ms=120000, grpc.keepalive_timeout_ms=20000, grpc.http2.max_pings_without_data=0, grpc.keepalive_permit_without_calls=1, name=peer0.org1.example.com:7051, grpc.ssl_target_name_override=peer0.org1.example.com, grpc.default_authority=peer0.org1.example.com, isProposalResponse=true
```

Help will be appreciated!

Comment: The clue is in the response message `TypeError: Assignment to constant variable., stack=Error: transaction returned with failure: TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.` There is an issue in your chaincode where it is trying to assign a value to a variable declared as a constant

Answer (score 0):

The error you are receiving is tunneled from the chaincode to the sdk.
Essentially is not related to the SDK but the chaincode.

Go to the machine with Hyperledger installed, and open logs for the dev peer.
You will find the same error

```
[Query]: evaluate: Query ID "[object Object]" of peer "peer0.org1.example.com:7051" failed: message=transaction returned with failure: TypeError: Assignment to constant variable., stack=Error: transaction returned with failure: TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.
```

and you will get that the problem is related to the chaincode.
I don't know how did you write your contract, if Go or other languages, but the message is clear: you declared a const and you are assinging it a new value.
Check your code, re-deploy the contract and you solve.